# How to handle non-email when importing Outlook email data into Excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to import all mails received and sent the past year.

For the received mails works, but the code stops when importing the sent mails. Specifically for the `OutlookMail.To` property. It stops when it gets to an accepted invitation for a meeting that I have sent.

Is there a way to bypass all the accepted invitations that I have sent and only get the emails?

```vb
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder1 As MAPIFolder
Dim Folder2 As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder1 = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Folder2 = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder1.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("H5").Value And OutlookMail.ReceivedTime <= Range("I5").Value Then
        Range("C4").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("A4").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("B4").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        i = i + 1
    End If

j = 1

Next OutlookMail

For Each OutlookMail In Folder2.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("H5").Value And OutlookMail.ReceivedTime <= Range("I5").Value Then
        Range("f4").Offset(j, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("d4").Offset(j, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("E4").Offset(j, 0).Value = OutlookMail.To
        
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder1 = Nothing
Set Folder2 = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: same way that you would sort marbles by color ... you look at the object

Comment: `If TypeOf OutlookMail Is MailItem Then`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (refactoring a bit)

```vb
Sub GetFromOutlook()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Namespace, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ListFolder olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox), ws.Range("C4")
    ListFolder olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail), ws.Range("F4")

End Sub

'List info for all mail items in `fldr`, starting at `rng`
Sub ListFolder(fldr As MAPIFolder, rng As Range)
    Dim itm As Variant, i As Long
    For Each itm In fldr.Items
        If TypeOf itm Is MailItem Then   'is this a mail item?
            'faster to write whole row in one shot
            rng.Cells(1).Offset(i).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                Array(itm.Subject, itm.ReceivedTime, itm.to)
            i = i + 1 'increment row
        End If 'is a mail object
    Next itm
End Sub
```